# Why is this Raku program producing a Seq of Array rather than a simple Array?

Tags: arrays, hashmap, sequence, push, raku

```
my %f;
for $*HOME.dir() -> $file {
    my $filename = $file.basename;
    %f{$filename}.push: $file, rand;
}
my $p = %f.pick; # just need any old random element
say $p.^name;
say "{$p.values.^name} has {$p.values.elems} elements";
say "{$p.values[0].^name} has {$p.values[0].elems} elements";

say '';
say $*RAKU;
say $*DISTRO;
say $*KERNEL;
say $*VM;
```

Output:

```
Pair
Seq has 1 elements
Array has 2 elements

Raku (6.d)
macos (13.2.1)
darwin
moar (2023.02)
```

Why is the `.values` of `$p` a `Seq` of `Array`, rather than a simple `Array`?

Comment: Does calling `first` on a hash make sense? Aren't Raku hashes supposed to be in random order?

Comment: You are correct.  I've edited the question to make it clearer that I'm just picking one element and that order has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is the `.values` of `%f` a `Seq` of `Array`, rather than a simple `Array`?

First, as @codesections has pointed out, it's not `%f`, it's a single element from `%f` (the "first" one, which is misleading, but that's a red herring).

So it's the `.values` of a `Pair`.

---

The doc for `Pair.values` says:

> ```
> multi method values(Pair:D: --> List:D)
> ```
>
> Returns a `List` containing the value of the invocant.

The doc says it should be a `List` (neither a `Seq` nor an `Array`).

Oops.

---

The current `.values` method declaration in [`main/src/core.c/Pair.pm6`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/6a2fee72e677124253bf073f9513f832798721a9/src/core.c/Pair.pm6#L84-L86) is:

```
multi method values(Pair:D:) {
    Seq.new(Rakudo::Iterator.OneValue($!value))
}
```

So that's why you're getting a `Seq`.

But *should* you be? Why does the actual result not match the doc? What needs to be fixed?

---

One possibility is the doc has always been wrong. Git blame shows it was written in mid 2016. Was the doc once right but Rakudo changed?

I joined the self-serve `#whateverable` IRC bot channel (using [kiwiirc](https://kiwiirc.com/nextclient/irc.libera.chat/#whateverable)), and then entered:

```
c: say (:a).values ~~ List
```

That ran [`commitable6`](https://github.com/Raku/whateverable/wiki/Committable), one of a family of [Raku IRC bots](https://github.com/Raku/whateverable/wiki), to test what the result was of running that code on versions of the Rakudo compiler.

A couple minutes later I got [a report showing that Rakudo did indeed return a `List` -- *until 2017.08*](https://gist.github.com/Whateverable/85ce26af74aadace5d9825e70d42a356).

What happened in 2017.08?

---

[The git blame report for `main/src/core.c/Pair.pm6`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blame/main/src/core.c/Pair.pm6) shows [a Liz commit](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/30584dac2fe231038c5bea557946a41310e9fd0f):

> Streamline the standard Seq methods on Pair
>
> - add dedicated .iterator
> - make sure that .keys/kv/values/pairs/antipairs produce a Seq
>   instead of a List, just as they do on any other object.

So that's why Rakudo changed so that `Pair.values` returns a `Seq`.

I just checked, and the doc for `Pairs.kv` is also wrong, and I think it's best to presume the doc for .keys/kv/values/pairs/antipairs will all be wrong too.

---

I hope to write up my conclusions this weekend, but will publish what I have so far.

Comment: Does this mean that calling `.values` on a `Pair` will always return a `Seq` with exactly one element?

Comment:  `say :a<a b c>.values.elems` yields `1` in a 2022 Rakudo.  [what I think is the relevant code](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/837a2eb87b25dcd48bf75bc828086c9c5b4074c5/src/core.c/Rakudo/Iterator.pm6#L3245-L3253) looks like it will ensure the `Seq` will contain just a single element.  [What looks to me like the most appropriate *roast* test](https://github.com/Raku/roast/blob/dffc2a4cec4a1b91a14289a88cead3ceecd5f5b4/S32-hash/keys_values.t#L31-L33) only tests a pair whose value is scalar (singular), not one whose value is non-scalar (plural).  I've not drawn any conclusions yet.

Answer (score 7):

As your `say $p.^name` line shows, `$p` is a `Pair`.  The value of this `Pair` is an `Array`; and if you called `$p.value`, you'd get that `Array`.  But `$p.values` (with an "s") returns a sequence of all of `$p`'s values – that is,`Seq` containing one `Array`.

> Why is the .values of %f a Seq of Array

(I'm not sure this was a typo, but note that you called `.values` on the `.first` element of `%f`, not on `%f` itself.  Calling `.values` on all of `%f` would also give you a `Seq` of `Array`s, but with more elements (one for each entry in `%f`.  Also note that `%f` (a `Hash`) isn't ordered, and thus `.first` doesn't return a consistent element – which is **very rarely** what you want.)

Comment: Ah, I should have used `.value`, not `.values`!  Thank you, was very clear.